# Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In issue

Tags: jenkins, plugins

Can anyone give me a right syntax for plugin "Extended Choice Parameter Plug-In" ?

I use configuratiom:

[image]

File list1.txt contains key=value pairs:

```
CERT=kyiv-linux-machine3-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
CERT=kyiv-linux-machine4-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
CERT=kyiv-linux-machine5-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
```

But when I start job - it only shows LAST key=value pair.

[image]

I cannot understand, what I missed either in configuration or in txt file format.

Can anyone five me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning 3 different values to the same key 'CERT'.
Update your file to have this content:

`CERT=kyiv-linux-machine3-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn,kyiv-linux-machine4-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn,kyiv-linux-machine5-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn`

Or if the values don't show, try with a comma and space as delimiter:

`CERT=kyiv-linux-machine3-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn, kyiv-linux-machine4-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn, kyiv-linux-machine5-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn`

Comment: Ok, I updated in your way - CERT=kyiv-linux-machine3-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn,kyiv-linux-machine4-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn,kyiv-linux-machine5-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn. But now plugin says that "file exists, but the provided key "CERT" doesnt exist in this property file."

Comment: I get that warning whilst editing the job configuration, but on saving it all worked fine.

Comment: was able to get all values only by adding spaces after commas, e.g.      CERT=kyiv-linux-machine3-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn, kyiv-linux-machine4-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn, kyiv-linux-machine5-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn 
(spaces and commas after values).

You can edit your andwer and I will mark it as a correct

Comment: Strange, it works for me as per original answer. Glad it works though, updated as suggested.